# WIX append data to file during installation

Tags: file, wix, append

I was just wondering what would be the easiest way to get WIX to append some lines to a configuration file (it is a matlab file) of other application, basically what I need is:

- Find where a third party application is installed (that I can handle)
- Append some lines to a configuration file of this third party application

I figure I would need to use a custom action right? But what would be the easiest way?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a custom action.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what format the configuration file is but generally speaking, it's easiest to avoid custom actions altogether if possible.

For INI files, you can use the [IniFile Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_inifile.htm)

For XML files, you can use the [XmlConfig Element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/util_xsd_xmlconfig.htm) located in the WiX Util Extension

Comment: it is actually a matlab file. So I cannot use the links you sent me.